# Best way to pass multiple keys and values together in a function?

Tags: c#, api, data-structures

I am a bit stuck here. I have a complicated API that was designed by a third party to retrieve User and Business data with custom search criteria. The search criteria syntax and format is not relevant but I am having to pass multiple keys and corresponding values. I need help creating the function.

Currently I have this function in my interface:

```
Response GetUser(
        List<string> keys,
        List<string> values,
        List<string> fieldsToReturn= null
        );
```

What's the best way to pass multiple keys and values where they can be tied/mapped together? And as one parameter? Key and value must match in count 1:1. Value is a search value that is tied to its corresponding key.

I already have pretty good validation with the current setup that it works okay, but I'm reconsidering and wanting to make key and value passed together to avoid too many unforseen input validation issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the value tuple syntax

```
GetUser(IEnumerable<(string Key, string Value)> keyValues)
```

This provides guaranteed matching between key values. I think it also communicates better that this is not intended for lookups, as a dictionary would.

Comment: what about a List<Tuple<string,string>> where I leverage iteration in the list for indexing? Or is that basically the same intent?

Comment: @Derek R , yes, `List<Tuple<string,string>> ` would be the same intent. I think ValueTuple has a nicer syntax than `Tuple<>` and it lets you name the fields. Pick whatever collection type that suits your purpose, `List`, `IReadOnlyList` `IEnumerable`, whatever. Typically you would pick the "smallest" interface that fulfills your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("key1", "value1");
dict.Add("key2", "value2");

dict["key1"] // this will get you "value1"
```

This way every key corresponds to only one value.

Pass it on to the function like this

```
Response GetUser(
    Dictionary<string, string> dict,
    List<string> fieldsToReturn= null
    );
```